# Customizing Django Shop app

Tags: django, e-commerce

I'm actually building a e-commerce systeme with Django. The most important difference to a traditional e-commerce is, that we don't sell single products. The products that we sell is a set of several small products and the costumers can build these sets by their own. Important is also that these small products stick together and the order in which the costumer selects the products is important. The price of the product is the sum of all selected small products plus a basic price.

This is a snippet from my model:

```
class SmallProduct(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    price = CurrencyField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='img/product/')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)

class Product(models.Model):
    small_products = models.ManyToManyField(SmallProduct, through='Ordering')
    #some other fields

class Ordering(models.Model):
    small_product = models.ForeignKey(SmallProduct)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I tried the Django Shop app and Satchmo but these apps does not fit my requirements. I dont want to rewrite a whole shop system, so I would be really glad if anyone has a smart idea how I can customize one of these apps to fit my requirements. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

U may try Cartridge which allows u to hook the payment steps and gives a control to you on shopping cart and other shopping objects. Also it allows u to add extra fields to the models without monkey patching.

U can do easily what u told with Cartridge.This link may give u an opinion about that:

http://cartridge.jupo.org/integration.html